# Custom Timeline's tooltip to display primitive values and objects together

Tags: anychart

I've been trying to create custom Tooltip for my Timeline but can't find a way to display value from a nested object alongside with primitive types.

Data example:

```
{
    id: 12345,
    start_time: "2020-03-31T16:00:40Z",
    end_time: "2020-03-31T18:30:40Z"
    created_by: {
       username: "mary_jane",
       first_name: "Mary",
       last_name: "Jane"
    },

}
```

Code example:

```
const data = makeDataSet(dataFromAPI).mapAs({name: "id", start: "start_time", end: "end_time"});
const customTooltip = "Id: {%id}" + "\nCreated by: {%created_by}";

const chart = anychart.timeline();
const exampleChart = chart.range(data).
exampleChart.tooltip().format(customTooltip)
```

It displays tooltip like this:

```
Id: 12345
Created by: [object Object] //{%created_by.username} won't display any value
```

What it should be displaying:

```
Id: 12345
Created by: mary_jane
```

My data object has multiple fields that are simple strings/number and those can be easily displayed with the string token but this doesn't work with fields where value is an object. For those cases it's possible to use formatting function after mapping an object, like so:

```
  const data = makeDataSet(dataFromAPI).mapAs({name: "id", value: "created_by"});
  exampleChart.tooltip().format(function(this:any) {
    return (
        "Id: " + this.name +                   //undefined
        "\nCreated by: " + this.value.username //mary_jane
    })
```

But how can I display both the "id" and "username" in one Tooltip? Is it possible to combine two methods of formatting? Or is there a way to access nested object inside string token (tried multiple ways including template strings)? Maybe a way to include string token in a formatting function (it looks like I can access only "value" so adding more keys didn't work)? Perhaps I should change my mapping?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[I'm using React + TypeScript, AnyChart version: 8.7.1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String tokens don't support complex structures like arrays or objects, only primitives in the point properties. It's a good choice for simple formatting. But you can implement the desired tooltip using a formatter callback function. The formatter context provides API to get any data field you need: `getData()`, `getMeta()`. I prepared a sample that describes how to implement the desired tooltip - https://playground.anychart.com/bvKyAFu6